# Validate Category Attribute

Tags: event-observer, model, category-attribute

I have extended `Mage_Catalog_Model_Category_Attribute_Source_Mode` (and it's Resource model) to add two new modes `display_mode` values for Categories. Now I want to validate the value of that attribute when saving a category. Specifically, I want to make sure that `is_anchor` is always set to "No" when either of my two new modes are selected.

The problem is that neither `Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute_Backend_Abstract::beforeSave` nor `Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute_Backend_Abstract::validate` dispatch any events that I can listen for.

`Mage_Catalog_Model_Category` also has no `_beforeSave` method.

How can I validate category attributes on save? Thanks!

Comment: what about the event `catalog_category_save_before` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually `Mage_Catalog_Model_Category` does possess the event `_beforeSave()`. In order to see that, you need to look on that class with wide eyes :)

`Mage_Catalog_Model_Category` directly does not define `_beforeSave`. However you can see that, this class inherits from another class `Mage_Catalog_Model_Abstract` and it does possess `_beforeSave`. It looks like this

```
 protected function _beforeSave()
{
    $this->unlockAttributes();
    return parent::_beforeSave();
}
```

You can see that, this class again call its parent class. That parent class is nothing but `Mage_Core_Model_Abstract`. There you can see that `_beforeSave` defined like this.

```
protected function _beforeSave()
{
    if (!$this->getId()) {
        $this->isObjectNew(true);
    }
    Mage::dispatchEvent('model_save_before', array('object'=>$this));
    Mage::dispatchEvent($this->_eventPrefix.'_save_before', $this->_getEventData());
    return $this;
}
```

This function dispatches two events. Second one is important here. You can see that, it uses an `event prefix` in that event. Now take a look on `Mage_Catalog_Model_Category`. You can see that, it actually defines an event prefix there.

```
protected $_eventPrefix     = 'catalog_category';
```

This means, **whenever category section is trying to save, `_beforeSave` method generates a unique event with name `catalog_category_save_before`.** I think , you can use that event to save any category attribute

Hope that helps

Comment: Because there is no explicit way for me to tie into the category validation, I had to do a `Mage::throwException` from the `_before_save` observer, but it did the job. Thanks!